# creating arrow keys on center of screen

Tags: android, android-layout

i am writing an application to control a robot
for controlling i need ( up, down , right, left ) keys
i used eclipse designer to create it but maybe it is not possible
i want to create something like this :
 [image: arrow keys]
 how can i create buttons like this in center of screen ?
is there  a better way to create arrow keys on android ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go :

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<View
    android:id="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_width="30dp"
    android:layout_height="30dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/view1"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView3"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/view1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/view1"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Of course, you can replace ImageView with anything else like an ImageButton.
Be sure, if you change the name of the first view, tu update the name in the 4 ImageView.
And be aware that the corners of each image are overlapping each other.

Comment: How Can I Bring It a little To Below?

Comment: You just have to move your View (@+id/view1) and everything should fallow.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using ImageButtons and setting the background for each to a State List Drawable xml file. This will change the image between states(focused, pressed, etc).

The tricky part would be positioning each so that they orient themselves in this sort of "box" you have above.

Just create some PNGs of each button in their positions. Up button points up, left points left etc. Then use RelativeLayout to position them with respect to each other. You can also use Buttons as well